# Left/right caret navigation in mixed RTL/LTR text

Tags: internationalization

Consider these two `<input>`'s: http://jsfiddle.net/T7gUX/
They contain mix of English and Hebrew/Arabic characters (both use Right-To-Left direction).

Question is about VK_LEFT/VK_RIGHT (keyboard keys) handling in such texts, we have two options:

1. FF/GC - LEFT/RIGHT are always
   handled in visual order - no matter
   directionality of the character
   underneath the caret - LEFT moves caret to the left always.
2. IE - LEFT/RIGHT match left/right on
   RTL characters but on LTR (e.g.
   English) caret movement is reversed - pressing LEFT moves caret to the right.

What is the correct behavior? If "correct" term is applicable here at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say, but IE way is correct. MS have dedicated people to do i18n and from what I can say, IE is the best web browser in terms of i18n (although still far from being correct).

As far as I know, all other text box controls in Windows would behave just like IE. It seems that Gecko (is it the source of the problem?) implements this behavior incorrectly (ignoring Unicode character directionality).

BTW. To me sudden change of direction when "scrolling" is a bit confusing... However it seems to be right for people used to frequently entering bi-directional text.

Comment: Consider this variation: http://jsfiddle.net/T7gUX/1/ 
There is an input with dir=rtl that contains only LTR characters. Caret direction is still reversed there. Seems like wrong for me.
Problem is that I don't know personally any of RTL language so my personal opinion is not that relevant.

Comment: I am not sure if you are seeing the same what I do, but IE9 seem to behave exactly opposite to what it should - moving caret left when I press right arrow on English (LTR) text and right on Hebrew... It seems to be a defect.

Comment: That is what I've noticed so asking. With SHIFT+LEFT/RIGHT (selection) all browsers behave the same.